# Group Count by Minute Interval

Tags: sql

I have a query that populates the time a customer is in a given place.

| ID | Loc | LocID | Entered | Left |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1F | FGH | f42 | 2022-08-01 13:25:00.0000 | 2022-08-01 13:46:00.0000 |
| 1a | ABC | a23 | 2022-08-02 09:14:00.0000 | 2022-08-02 10:35:00.0000 |
| 2a | ABC | a23 | 2022-08-02 09:56:00.0000 | 2022-08-02 11:05:00.0000 |
| 3b | BCD | b84 | 2022-08-02 13:43:00.0000 | 2022-08-02 13:59:00.0000 |

I want to get the count of people in a location at a given interval.

| Loc | LocID | Entered | Left | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FGH | f42 | 2022-08-01 13:00:00.0000 | 2022-08-01 13:30:00.0000 | 1 |
| FGH | f42 | 2022-08-01 13:30:00.0000 | 2022-08-01 14:00:00.0000 | 1 |
| ABC | a23 | 2022-08-02 09:00:00.0000 | 2022-08-02 09:30:00.0000 | 1 |
| ABC | a23 | 2022-08-02 09:30:00.0000 | 2022-08-02 10:00:00.0000 | 2 |
| ABC | a23 | 2022-08-02 10:00:00.0000 | 2022-08-02 10:30:00.0000 | 2 |
| ABC | a23 | 2022-08-02 10:30:00.0000 | 2022-08-02 11:00:00.0000 | 2 |
| ABC | a23 | 2022-08-02 11:00:00.0000 | 2022-08-02 11:30:00.0000 | 1 |
| BCD | b84 | 2022-08-02 13:30:00.0000 | 2022-08-02 14:00:00.0000 | 1 |

So far I have

```
WITH main AS
(
    -- the main query I'm working from
)
SELECT
    Loc, 
    LocID, 
    DATEADD(MINUTE, (DATEPART(MINUTE, entertime) / 30) * 30, (DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, entertime), 0))) AS Entered,
    DATEADD(MINUTE, (DATEPART(MINUTE, timeleft) / 30) * 30, (DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, timeleft), 0))) AS Left, 
FROM
    main
GROUP BY 
   loc, locid,
   DATEADD(MINUTE, (DATEPART(MINUTE, entertime) / 30) * 30,
   (DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, entertime), 0))),
   DATEADD(MINUTE, (DATEPART(MINUTE, timeleft) / 30) * 30, (DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, timeleft), 0)))
```

This is what it outputs

| Loc | LocID | Entered | Left |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FGH | f42 | 2022-08-01 13:00:00.0000 | 2022-08-01 13:30:00.0000 |
| ABC | a23 | 2022-08-02 09:00:00.0000 | 2022-08-02 10:30:00.0000 |
| ABC | a23 | 2022-08-02 09:30:00.0000 | 2022-08-02 11:00:00.0000 |

Comment: What is the given interval you want to get the count for -- every second?  every minute? every day?  What?

Comment: @hogan Hi, sorry every 30 minute

Comment: Each make and version of database server has its own dialect of SQL, especially for datestamp handling. Please [edit] your question to add a [tag](//stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database you use. [tag:postgresql]? [tag:mysql]? [tag:sql-server]? [tag:oracle]? [tag:google-bigquery]? [tag:amazon-redshift]? Another?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it is very hard to give a specific answer since you don't show any of your data model or details about your specific code and implementation.

Instead, I'm going to give a generic answer.  I'll assume the you are using SQL Server and the @start and @end represent the start and end period which you want counts for.  Also, I will call the table that has data YourTableNameHere.

Plan:  First use a recursive CTE to create a table with each interval's start and end timestamps, then join that table back to the user data and compute the counts... like this:

```
 WITH intervals AS
 (
      SELECT
        1 as rowNumber, 
        @start as startTS, 
        DATEADD(minute,@start,30) as endTS 
    UNION ALL
      SELECT 
        inter.rowNumber+1,
        DATEADD(minute,inter.startTS,30) as startTS,
        DATEADD(minute,inter.endTS,30) as endTS
      FROM intervals inter
      WHERE inter.endTS < @end
 )
 SELECT INTE.rowNumber, COUNT(*)
 FROM intervals INTE
 JOIN YourTableNameHere TAB ON INTE.startTS BETWEEN TAB.entered AND TAB.Left
                            OR INTE.endTS   BETWEEN TAB.entered AND TAB.Left
 GROUP BY INTE.rowNumber
```

I see there are a number if details in your question -- like you also want to group by location -- or other things.  Just add those into the GROUP BY (and the select) as needed for your purpose.